# BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2443: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isAdmin()

Tags: laravel, authentication, production

I have installed a laravel 5.4 with built in auth. The `Auth::user()->isAdmin()` method is working on laravel's test environment (php artisan serve), but not on production server. All other Model`s methods work without any problems.

Here is my User model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'country_id' => 'int',
        'admin' => 'boolean'
    ];
    //
    protected $dates = [
        'created',
        'modified'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'userid',
        'password',
        'surname',
        'givenname',
        'admin',
        'email',
        'country_id',
        'placename',
        'postcode',
        'address',
        'phone',
        'mobil',
        'fax',
        'created',
        'modified',
        'title'
    ];

    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return $this->admin; 
    }

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Country::class);
    }

    public function log_logins()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\LogLogin::class, 'userid', 'userid');
    }

    public function firms()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Firm::class, 'users_firms', 'user_id', 'firms_id');
                    //->withPivot('id');
    }
}
```

**Error message**

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2443: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isAdmin()

My Stack Trace is:

```
[2017-04-25 09:05:00] local.ERROR: exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isAdmin()' in /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2443
Stack trace:
0 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1239): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->__call('isAdmin', Array)
1 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1239): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->isAdmin()
2 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1332): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('isAdmin', Array)
3 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1332): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->isAdmin()
4 /var/www/test/app/Http/Controllers/SearchController.php(26): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('isAdmin', Array)
5 /var/www/test/app/Http/Controllers/SearchController.php(26): App\User->isAdmin()
6 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\SearchController->index()
7 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
8 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('index', Array)
9 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(204): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\SearchController), 'index')
10 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(160): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
11 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(559): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
12 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
13 /var/www/test/vendor/mcamara/laravel-localization/src/Mcamara/LaravelLocalization/Middleware/LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter.php(55): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
14 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
15 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
16 /var/www/test/vendor/mcamara/laravel-localization/src/Mcamara/LaravelLocalization/Middleware/LocaleSessionRedirect.php(31): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
17 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleSessionRedirect->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
18 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
19 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
20 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
21 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
22 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(65): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
23 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
24 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
25 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
26 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
27 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
28 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
29 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
30 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
31 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
32 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
33 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
34 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
35 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
36 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
37 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
38 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(561): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
39 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(520): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
40 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(498): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
41 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
42 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
43 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
44 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
45 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
46 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
47 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
48 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
49 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
50 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
51 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
52 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
53 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
54 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
55 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
56 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(149): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
57 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
58 /var/www/test/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
59 {main}
```

Can anyone tell me what can be a problem? I have some experience with laravel, but this seems as a mystery.

Thanks.

Comment: Need to remove isAdmin()

Comment: You can just use `Auth::check()->admin` instead

Comment: Thanks, it works too, but the problem was something else...
I have redeclared the User class, and that version did not have method isAdmin().
However, thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: Nice to know that